# Azure PostgreSQL Point In Time Restore not working

Tags: postgresql, azure, pitr

We have a Postgre database in Azure and we had a problem where all rows from a table where deleted.
We tried using the Point In Time Restore option in de azure portal but the database that is created has the same data as the currently running database. we also tried other other dates and times.

- database problem was at 06-05-21 - 10:30 AM.
- restore database was set to 06-05-21 - 10:25 AM. (same data as
  currently running database)
- restore database was set tot 05-05-21 - 11:50 PM. (same data as
  currently running database)

What step are we missing.

Comment: Can you confirm you restore db successfully done without any issue ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-restore-server-portal  and check the problem occurrence time as well

Comment: @RahulShukla

The restore was done without a issue.
Today I tested the restore on a new database server and everything was working as expected.
Going to test some more on our current database. Keep you updated.

Comment: @JeroenvanHeel, did you have a lot of FW rules and VNET service endpoints associated to the database ? Once you restore in the new server, those are lost. Have you find a way to do that automatically ?