# Azure database for MySQL recovery

Tags: mysql, azure

Someone accidently remove the azure database for mysql that was assigned to an app service(wordpress). Now when i try to access the website i get "Error establishing a database connection". I have found the steps to recover the Db here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-restore-dropped-server?fbclid=IwAR3-bhiQINOwl8pLdP-zpSNRQF_ZkDKuqJ2StOkZi68fSY9WZmSYR7h_mlA , I followed this steps and I got the code 202(which is supposed to be successful) but nothing is happening. It did not restore my DB and I still cannot use my website. Do you have any ideas how this recovery should behave?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help in database admin type of questions like this one.

Comment: Same as this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67417291/azure-postgresql-point-in-time-restore-not-working?noredirect=1#comment119184376_67417291